# Changepoint Analysis in R for Time Series Data

Tags: r, computational-statistics, games, frequency-severity

I'm new to R and statistics in general. My background is in Software Development, and I've tasked myself to solve a problem in a 3rd party application.  This application is a Game, and I'd like to measure the existence of a performance problem.

I measure performance in Frames Per Second (FPS), and for some reason under high load the system exhibits periodic drops (hesitation) in performance.  I want to measure the frequency, severity of this drop in performance.

The idea is to measure whether changes in the codebase/testing-conditions has changed the base & hesitation performance.

I acknowledge this is similar to time-series analysis of data like stocks, temperature, etc. However the resources out there that I would like to apply hasnt quite sunk in yet.  So I'm looking for set a responses for me to review and hopefully teach myself.

I've been able to load data into R Studio and create graphs. I've followed a few other answers to create some smoothed lines, but it didnt quite work for my dataset.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbRNC.jpg - An album of the data graphs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Soon I will be answering my own question, I enrolled myself in the Coursera class for Computing for Data Analysis. I will provide detailed steps taken here once complete.